# Liferay Page Administrator

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I need that each page is administered by one person or group of persons.

Do I need to create one role each for every page I have to administer(Page1 administrator, page 2 administrator) or can I just create one generic role named "Page Administrator" and have some thing like a user having Page Administrator role can manage only page1 and similarly another user having the same "Page Administrator" can only manage "page2"? This is to avoid creating as many roles as there are pages in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends... The easiest and most maintainable way to assign permissions in Liferay is through roles per site. If you have 1 page per site, you're good to go with a site role. You can build the navigation from many different sites, an example is [this POC app](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/27362781) by yours truly.

If you create roles (or teams) per page, be aware that page management is a different beast than content management: All of the pages of one site share the same content. Thus it might be hard to solve, if you also want the page administrators to maintain the content.

Comment: Makes sense Olaf. The main problem is their existing website has a way(custom code) to assign a page admin role to certain users of a page. And their pages dont have any logical grouping. Each page is managed by a page admin. I dont think it can be possible in liferay unless I create one role for each page. Your site concept looks inviting if I can manage certain pages to a group. Btw versioning of a page can only be enabled if Staging is enabled right?

Comment: Not sure about the implications of converting the current implementation to another - I'll leave this up to you. And yes, versioning is a sub-feature of staging